# jQuery - Select first cell of a given row?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table with images in one column.  When I click the image,  would like to get the text value of the first column in that row.

I can get the whole row with this:

```
var a = $(this).parents('tr').text();
```

However, I cannot isolate the first cell of the row.

I've tried

```
var a = $(this).parents('tr td:first').text();
```

But that just returns the first cell of the entire table.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

How about?

```
var a = $('td:first', $(this).parents('tr')).text();
```

Comment: In Prototype, you might go: var a = this.up('tr').down('td').innerHTML

Comment: @arbales Solution are meant to be posted as answers, not comments.

Comment: @DanielElliott Please explain how your answer works and why it is a good idea. Code-only answers were acceptable a decade ago, but now new developers want to find a solutions AND be educated by the same page.

Answer (score 30):

Here's another option:

```
var a = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
```

Comment: Please explain how your answer works and why it is a good idea.  Code-only answers were acceptable a decade ago, but now new developers want to find a solutions AND be educated by the same page.