# Selecting second cell of a row using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML table

```
<table>
<tr class="trSelected">
<td>One</td>
<td>two</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I just want to get the `text` in the `second column` (ie,'`two`')

I tried

```
$('.trSelected td').eq(2).val()
```

but it returs an empty string
How it is possible through jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Select first cell of a given row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425937/jquery-select-first-cell-of-a-given-row)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the following construction:

```
$('.trSelected td').eq(1).text()
```

or

```
$('.trSelected td:eq(1)').text()
```

`eq` selector uses zero-based index. Also you have to use `text` method, not `val`.

Answer (score 4):

List Indices start from 0, not from 1.

You are trying to select column 3, which does not exist. Also, the .val() method is only used for getting and setting form fields, not normal html elements. Use .text() instead!

```
$('.trSelected td').eq(1).text()
```

might work.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector to get the second cell

```
$(".trSelected td:nth-child(2)").val()
```

Answer (score 2):

First for all, [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)'s argument is a 0-based index, so to get the second element, you'd need to call `eq(1)`.

Secondly, the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method is used to retrieve the value from inputs, you're dealing with `td` elements, not inputs.

```
$('.trSelected td').eq(1).text()
```

will do [what you're expecting](http://jsfiddle.net/hE7Qn/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the nth-child selector or you should use eq(1). Also, you should use .text() or .html() instead of .val()

An example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/heTyW/